# How do I reduce the padding between rows in sidebar menu?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a shinydashboard that has a sidebar menu. I would like to reduce the padding between the rows. Is there a way to do format using css or some other approach?

[image]

Here's the code:

```
 menuItem("Lavaan",
                       tabName = "lavaan",
                       icon = icon("bar")),
              conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'lavaan'",
                              fluidRow(
                                 
                                     splitLayout(cellWidths = c("auto", "auto", "auto"),
                                                 cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 0px"),
                                                 actionButton("add_btn", "+"),
                                                 actionButton("rm_btn", "-"),
                                                 p(strong("Latent Variables"))
                                 )),
                               
                         
                                     splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"),
                                                 cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 0px"),
                                                 uiOutput("textbox_ui"),
                                                 uiOutput("textbox_ui1")),
                               
                                 
                                     splitLayout(cellWidths = c("auto", "auto", "auto"),
                                                 cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 8px"),
                                                 p(strong("Regressions")),
                                                 actionButton("add_btn", "+"),
                                                 actionButton("rm_btn", "-"))
                                 ),
```

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `label=NULL` in your `TextInput()`, you can get the following output:

[image: output]

If you wish to make further modification, you may need to try css.